# cmake cannot find library when linking library to another application

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am trying to make generate a shared library of an existing application, so that i can link it to gtest application.
My main applications cmake file looks like this:

```
project(audiodLib CXX C)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

## Lets store all the source code in ${SOURCES}
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp src/controls/*.cpp src/controls/pulse/*.cpp src/modules/*.cpp src/product/*.cpp src/umi/*.cpp src/umi/modules/*.cpp src/umi/soundSettings/*.cpp src/utils/*.cpp utils/*.cpp pmtrace/*.c)

##Lets generate the library
##Please note, here instead of ${SOURCES} if i try to directly add source code, I always get
##an error saying that cmake could not find any *.cpp files
add_library(audiodLib SHARED ${SOURCES})

##Lets link it with libraries
target_link_libraries(audiodLib     ${GLIB2_LDFLAGS}
                ${LUNASERVICE_LDFLAGS}
                ${PBNJSON_C_LDFLAGS}
                ${LUNAPREFS_LDFLAGS}
                ${POWERD_LDFLAGS}
                ${PMLOGLIB_LDFLAGS}
                ${NYXLIB_LDFLAGS}
                ${LIBPBNJSON_LDFLAGS}
                ${PULSE_LDFLAGS}
                ${LTTNG_UST_LDFLAGS}
                ${URCU_BP_LDFLAGS}
                ${PULSE_SIMPLE_LDFLAGS}
                ${WEBOSI18N_LDFLAGS}
                pthread
                rt
                dl
                -lsnapshot-boot
                )

##Lets make this library availabel for other modules
install(TARGETS audiodLib LIBRARY DESTINATION ${WEBOS_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

After compilation, libaudiodLib.so is generated in /usr/lib directory.
And now if I try to access the audiodLib in my gtest code like this:

```
##${WEBOS_INSTALL_LIBDIR} = /usr/lib/
include_directories(${WEBOS_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
target_link_libraries(${GTEST_EXECUTABLE}
    ${WEBOS_GTEST_LIBRARIES}
    ${GLIB2_LDFLAGS}
    ${LUNASERVICE_LDFLAGS}
    ${PBNJSON_C_LDFLAGS}
    ${LUNAPREFS_LDFLAGS}
    ${POWERD_LDFLAGS}
    ${PMLOGLIB_LDFLAGS}
    ${NYXLIB_LDFLAGS}
    ${LIBPBNJSON_LDFLAGS}
    ${PULSE_LDFLAGS}
    ${LTTNG_UST_LDFLAGS}
    ${URCU_BP_LDFLAGS}
    ${PULSE_SIMPLE_LDFLAGS}
    ${WEBOSI18N_LDFLAGS}
    pthread
    rt
    dl
    -lsnapshot-boot
    -laudiodLib
    )
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot find -laudiodLib
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
audiod/
CMakeList
    |src
|tests
    CMakelist
```

If someone can point out what I am doing wrong, it would be of great help. I am kind of stuck and clueless after spending 2-3 days on this.

Comment: audiodLib and gtest_audiod are different CMake invocations.
Also, after installing the audiodLib, I wish to use the same in gtest/CMakelist.

Comment: It _could_ be as easy as running `ldconfig` to update your `ld.so` cache.

Comment: Thanks for you're time and suggestion @Botje unfortunately it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you rerun with `make VERBOSE=1` and paste the resulting linker invocation?

Comment: If I provide complete path, then my application is able to find the library, and the application works as per expectation. However I understand this approach is wrong, so i am looking for something generic.

Comment: Here is the error message:
| /home/work/user.name/o20_build/build-starfish/BUILD/work/board/lib32-audiod/audiod-10Feb_00/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm--linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/ld: cannot find -laudiodLib

| /home/work/user.name/o20_build/build-starfish/BUILD/work/board/lib32-audiod/audiod-10Feb_00/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm--linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/ld: cannot find -laudiodLib

Comment: You never mentioned you were cross-compiling! Then we *definitely* need to see the full link command (`make VERBOSE=1`) and last few lines of the output. Where in that directory tree is `libaudiodLib.so`  installed to?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by following edit:
target_link_libraries(${GTEST_EXECUTABLE}
    audiodLib    
    ${WEBOS_GTEST_LIBRARIES}
    ${GLIB2_LDFLAGS}
    ${LUNASERVICE_LDFLAGS}
    ${PBNJSON_C_LDFLAGS}
    ${LUNAPREFS_LDFLAGS}
    ${POWERD_LDFLAGS}
    ${PMLOGLIB_LDFLAGS}
    ${NYXLIB_LDFLAGS}
    ${LIBPBNJSON_LDFLAGS}
    ${PULSE_LDFLAGS}
    ${LTTNG_UST_LDFLAGS}
    ${URCU_BP_LDFLAGS}
    ${PULSE_SIMPLE_LDFLAGS}
    ${WEBOSI18N_LDFLAGS}
    pthread
    rt
    dl
    -lsnapshot-boot
    )

Comment: ERROR: lib32-audiod-1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85 do_package_qa: QA Issue: package lib32-audiod-ptest contains bad RPATH /lib32-audiod/audiod-1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85 in file /lib32-audiod/packages-split/lib32-audiod-ptest/opt/webos/tests/audiod/gtest_audiod
package lib32-audiod-ptest contains bad RPATH /lib32-audiod/audiod-1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85 in file /lib32-audiod/packages-split/lib32-audiod-ptest/opt/webos/tests/audiod/gtest_audiod [rpaths]
ERROR: lib32-audiod do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Task (virtual:multilib:lib32:/home/work/build-starfish/audiod.bb:do_package_qa)fail exit '1'

Comment: These comments should be edits to your question. By the looks of it, your build system is not happy with the RPATH entries created by CMake?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so very much for offering me suggestions, and pointers, I was finally able to sove the problem.
Regarding library not found issue, I resolved it by rearranging the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES as follows:

```
target_link_libraries(audiod
                audiodLib
                ${GLIB2_LDFLAGS}
                ${LUNASERVICE_LDFLAGS}
                ${PBNJSON_C_LDFLAGS}
                ${LUNAPREFS_LDFLAGS}
                ${POWERD_LDFLAGS}
                ${PMLOGLIB_LDFLAGS}
                ${NYXLIB_LDFLAGS}
                ${LIBPBNJSON_LDFLAGS}
                ${PULSE_LDFLAGS}
                ${LTTNG_UST_LDFLAGS}
                ${URCU_BP_LDFLAGS}
                ${PULSE_SIMPLE_LDFLAGS}
                ${WEBOSI18N_LDFLAGS}
                pthread
                rt
                dl
                -lsnapshot-boot
                )
```

And how i resolved the BAD RPATH Error during do_package_qa, I have already answerd it here:
[bitbake do_package_qa issue contains bad RPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180646/bitbake-do-package-qa-issue-contains-bad-rpath/60255452#60255452)