# bitbake do_package_qa issue contains bad RPATH

Tags: cmake, bitbake

I am clueless about an issue which i am facing.
During cross compiling one of the app, i am getting following error which is making no sense.
If someone can help me debug the issue, it would be really helpful.

```
ERROR: lib32-audiod-1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85-r26audiod-automation-10Feb_00 do_package_qa: QA Issue: package lib32-audiod-ptest contains bad RPATH /home/work/ashutosh.tripathi/o20_build/build-starfish/BUILD/work/o20-starfishmllib32-linux-gnueabi/lib32-audiod/1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85-r26audiod-automation-10Feb_00/audiod-1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85 in file /home/work/ashutosh.tripathi/o20_build/build-starfish/BUILD/work/o20-starfishmllib32-linux-gnueabi/lib32-audiod/1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85-r26audiod-automation-10Feb_00/packages-split/lib32-audiod-ptest/opt/webos/tests/audiod/gtest_audiod
package lib32-audiod-ptest contains bad RPATH /home/work/ashutosh.tripathi/o20_build/build-starfish/BUILD/work/o20-starfishmllib32-linux-gnueabi/lib32-audiod/1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85-r26audiod-automation-10Feb_00/audiod-1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85 in file /home/work/ashutosh.tripathi/o20_build/build-starfish/BUILD/work/o20-starfishmllib32-linux-gnueabi/lib32-audiod/1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85-r26audiod-automation-10Feb_00/packages-split/lib32-audiod-ptest/opt/webos/tests/audiod/gtest_audiod [rpaths]
ERROR: lib32-audiod-1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85-r26audiod-automation-10Feb_00 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: lib32-audiod-1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85-r26audiod-automation-10Feb_00 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/work/ashutosh.tripathi/o20_build/build-starfish/BUILD/work/o20-starfishmllib32-linux-gnueabi/lib32-audiod/1.0.0-161.jcl4tv.85-r26audiod-automation-10Feb_00/temp/log.do_package_qa.4873
ERROR: Task (virtual:multilib:lib32:/home/work/ashutosh.tripathi/o20_build/build-starfish/meta-lg-webos/meta-webos/recipes-multimedia/audiod/audiod.bb:do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2622 tasks of which 2608 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

Here is the audiod recipe file:

```
DEPENDS = "glib-2.0 libpbnjson luna-service2 pmloglib luna-prefs boost pulseaudio"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "\
    libasound \
    libasound-module-pcm-pulse \
    libpulsecore \
    pulseaudio \
    pulseaudio-lib-cli \
    pulseaudio-lib-protocol-cli \
    pulseaudio-misc \
    pulseaudio-module-cli-protocol-tcp \
    pulseaudio-module-cli-protocol-unix \
    pulseaudio-server \
"

WEBOS_VERSION = "1.0.0-161.open.12_49f981e4e5a599b75d893520b30393914657a4ae"
PR = "r26"

inherit webos_component
inherit webos_enhanced_submissions
inherit webos_cmake
inherit webos_library
inherit webos_daemon
inherit webos_system_bus
inherit webos_machine_dep
inherit gettext
inherit webos_lttng
inherit webos_public_repo
inherit webos_test_provider

# TODO: move to WEBOS_GIT_REPO_COMPLETE
WEBOS_REPO_NAME = "audiod-pro"
SRC_URI = "${WEBOS_PRO_GIT_REPO_COMPLETE}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

EXTRA_OECMAKE += "${@bb.utils.contains('WEBOS_LTTNG_ENABLED', '1', '-DWEBOS_LTTNG_ENABLED:BOOLEAN=True', '', d)}"

EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DAUDIOD_PALM_LEGACY:BOOLEAN=True"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DAUDIOD_TEST_API:BOOLEAN=True"

FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/alsa/"
FILES_${PN} += "/data"
FILES_${PN} += "${webos_mediadir}/internal"
```

Comment: Please post your recipe

Comment: edited the question, attached the recipe

Comment: I expect that there is something wrong between your cmake file and runtime path in yocto .. Try to use set_target_properties to set CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=TRUE.

Comment: where did you get "o20-starfishmllib32-linux-gnueabi" toolchain? please provide a link.

Comment: proprietary toolchain cannot share

Answer (score 2):

I would like to thank the stackoverflow community for the help offered.
Adding the following flags helped resolve the issue.
Posting it here, so that others may get some benefit from it, if they ever face similar problem

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
```

Or, skipping RPATH also does the job:

```
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

worked also by adding following line into the recipe:

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=TRUE"
```

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-cmake